# How to prove that limit exists and equals specific value/function? (Durrett Problem 1.5.7)

Tags: probability-theory, lebesgue-integral

> Let $f\geqslant 0$. (i) Show that $\int f\wedge n\ \mathrm d\mu\uparrow \int f\ \mathrm d\mu $ as $n\to\infty$. (ii) Use (i) to conclude that if $g$ is integrable  and $\varepsilon>0$ then we can pick $\delta>0$ so that $\mu(A)<\delta$ implies $\int_A |g|\ \mathrm d\mu <\varepsilon$.

In the above problem part - (i), I have the idea to define $f_n = \min(f, n)$ and then use the monotone convergence theorem. But this can be done only if we can show that $f_n$ is non-decreasing and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n = f$. I have already proved that the function is non-decreasing (by breaking it into cases and observing value of $f_{n+1} - f_{n}$), but I need some help with the second part.

Comment: Let $x\in \mathbb R$ be given. If $n\geq f(x)$, then $f_n(x) = f(x)$, thus $f_n \to f$ pointwise. Moreover, $f_{n+1} \geq f_n$. Indeed, for any $a \in \mathbb R$, one has $a\wedge (n+1)\geq a\wedge n$

Comment: @Andrew - Do you mean to say that the sequence $f_n$ is non-decreasing in terms of $n$ and bounded above by function $f$ (point-wise a.e.) then the limit exists and equals to $f$?

Comment: $x_n \to x$ as $n\to\infty$ if given $\epsilon>0$, there is $N$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $|x_n-x|<\epsilon$. Here, I am choosing $N = f(x)$ (or if you wish to be pedantic, I am choosing $N = \mathrm{ceiling\,}f(x))$

Comment: @Andrew, that is just limit's definition, I cannot understand how you use it here directly to show that limit exists and is equal to $f()$

Comment: Let $\epsilon>0$ and $x\in \mathbb R$ be given. Choose $N = f(x)$. If $n\geq N$, then $f_n(x) = f(x)\wedge n = f(x)$. Thus $|f_n(x)-f(x)| = 0<\epsilon$